# git push local changes to specific branch after fresh git install

Tags: git, github

I was working on a branch `user-ui` . When I tried to commit my changes it displayed the message saying git is corrupted.

So I deleted my `.git` folder and initialized git fresh. I followed the following steps.

```
git init
git remote add origin "${url}" // link to my repo 
git fetch
```

Now I want to push my changes to the branch I am working on. 
When I do `git branch` it didn't show any branch.
When I do `git checkout <tab>` it shows branch like `user-ui` and `origin/user-ui`

I am not sure what should I do next.

Need help

Comment: Do you know how many files you changed, i.e. how many files would have changes you plan to commit?  This is a complicated situation, and the fix isn't as simple as just adding an origin and going back to the way things were.

Comment: I know how many files I have changes. but the changes are many..

Comment: I will post an answer, but I think the easiest thing here is to just clone your repo again and then clobber the files you know whose changes you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted your entire `.git` folder, then the quickest fix to get it back, minus any working changes, would be to just create a new folder and clone it again:

```
mkdir new_folder
git clone ssh://aryan@github.com/path/to/your-repo.git
```

Now the `.git` folder in `new_folder` will be aware of the latest changes to all branches in the repo.  But of course your changes aren't there.  To get your work in there, you may simply copy/paste in the handful of files you changed.  As the source here you would use the version of those files in the original folder.  Then, just `git add` the files and commit as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow some steps to recover your work, Hope this will help you :)

- Copy and Paste your working directory to the other location and remove .git folder
- Clone your working repository
- Go to specific Branch
- Replace folder and files (backup directory) with current working.
- Compare and check your working files is it ok (I am using netbeans to find diff).
- If all ok then add files to git (git add  or git add -A)
  commit your changes and then pull and push that’s it.

Good luck.
Thanks,